# WPF: How to show Miss Spelled words in a Read-Only RichtextBox

Tags: wpf, richtextbox, readonly, spell-checking

I am looking for a solution that will show miss spelled words in read-only richtextbox. I have searched google, couldn't find any good solution that works. Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you checked [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/system.windows.controls.spellcheck(v=vs.110).aspx) link?

Comment: Thanks Lena, I can enable spell check, but if the field is read-only spell check doesn't show.  I am trying a solution. If I get it working I will post it.

Comment: What about try to imitate the read-only behavior: grab mouse, keyboard, focus etc events and prevent their propagation to the TextBox?